# Expand list by combining nested list and copying single values

Tags: java, combinatorics

I have a List containing strings and other lists.

Example:

```
List<Object> valuesList = new ArrayList<Object>();
valuesList.add("v0");
valuesList.add(Arrays.asList("v11", "v12"));
valuesList.add(Arrays.asList("v21", "v22"));
valuesList.add("v3");
```

I have to create a new List of Lists of strings that contain all combinations of nested lists and simple string members copied over the combinations. Sorry if it's not clear, may be clearer if you see what should I have for the example above, a list of lists:

```
list 1: v0 v11 v21 v3
list 2: v0 v12 v21 v3
list 3: v0 v11 v22 v3
list 4: v0 v12 v22 v3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick, using an iterative approach, and using `List<List<String>>` instead of `List<Object>` :

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<List<String>> baseLists = new ArrayList<>();
        baseLists.add(Arrays.asList("a01","a02"));
        baseLists.add(Arrays.asList("a11","a12"));
        baseLists.add(Arrays.asList("a21","a22","a23"));
        baseLists.add(Arrays.asList("a3"));
        System.out.println("Base lists: " + baseLists);
        List<List<String>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        // iterative solution
        baseLists.forEach(list -> {
                List<List<String>> newCombinations = new ArrayList();
                list.forEach(string -> {
                    List<List<String>> currentCombinations = new ArrayList();
                    // deep copy combinations
                    combinations.forEach(inlist -> currentCombinations.add(new ArrayList(inlist)));
                    if(currentCombinations.isEmpty()) {
                        currentCombinations.add(new ArrayList());
                    }
                    currentCombinations.forEach(inlist -> inlist.add(string));
                    newCombinations.addAll(currentCombinations);
                });
                combinations.clear();
                newCombinations.forEach(l -> combinations.add(l));
        });
        System.out.println("Combination lists: " + combinations);
    }
}
```

The output in this case is:

```
Base lists: [[a01, a02], [a11, a12], [a21, a22, a23], [a3]]
Combination lists: [[a01, a11, a21, a3], [a02, a11, a21, a3], [a01, a12, a21, a3], [a02, a12, a21, a3], [a01, a11, a22, a3], [a02, a11, a22, a3], [a01, a12, a22, a3], [a02, a12, a22, a3], [a01, a11, a23, a3], [a02, a11, a23, a3], [a01, a12, a23, a3], [a02, a12, a23, a3]]
```